# How to resolve warning messages (metadata object not found; SpatialLinesNULL class not exported) in my R package which extends S4 classes

Tags: r, inheritance, devtools, r-sp, r-package

This is my first question post on StackOverflow, so please correct any protocol errors I make.  But I have already benefitted greatly from answers to many other questions on the site, so before I go further I would like to **thank the community** that contributes to the site.

## Overview

I am using R, with RStudio, and packages `devtools` and `roxygen2` on a Windows 7 machine (full `session_info` at the end of the question)

I am trying to write a package of my own, which defines subclasses of the S4 class `SpatialLines` from the package `sp`, and also uses the package `rgeos`.  My problem relates to warning messages that I do not really understand, and cannot fully resolve, when I used devtools to `document` and 
`load_all` my package.

### Warning messages

The first message is

```
class "Spatial" is defined (with package slot ‘sp’) but no metadata object found to revise subclass information---not exported?  Making a copy in package ‘minweSpatialNULL’
```

When I resolve this, by adding an entry in the NAMESPACE file (without fully understanding why it is necessary), and then make one further change to the DESCRIPTION file I get a second message which has me beaten, thus far.

```
d> devtools::document()
Updating minweSpatialNULL documentation
Loading minweSpatialNULL
Error: class "SpatialLinesNULL" is not exported by 'namespace:rgeos'
```

### What I have tried, and the questions I am left with

I have googled and searched several sites looking for hints, but the closest I found was a brief thread from Dec 2011 asking where SpatialLinesNULL came from --- to which 
the answer was `rgeos`.
http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rspatial-devel/2011-December/000033.html

I have tried experimenting to understand what is wrong myself, and stepped
through code in the debugger till I got lost, way deeper than I could follow
well enough to figure out what was supposed to be happening.  In the process
have produced a small (not) working example of the issue, which is shown below.

I have 3 questions. They are summarised here, but really only make sense in the context of my (not) working toy example below :

- **Question 1** (after test1) Why does R need the (virtual?) superclass `Spatial` anyway, and why only when I have the *2nd generation* `MyClass2` defined in my code?
  *Clarification added* I had thought that the R packaging namespace mechanism would have taken care of any need to find and access antecedents /  superclasses once I had `@importClassesFrom`ed the class I actually use.
- **Question 2** (after test3) I am presuming that whatever the reason is for my first warning message, is also the reason for this similar message.
  Am I on the right track?
- **Question 3** (after test4) Is the warning from test3 and this 
  subsequent error something I can resolve myself (if so how)? 
  or do I need to ask the maintainer of the `rgeos` package
  for help (eg ask them to export `SpatialLinesNULL`)?

## Code example

The r code for my toy working example (stripped only of roxygen comments to save
space) is :

```
MyClass1 <- setClass('MyClass1', contains = c('SpatialLines'))
MyClass2 <- setClass('MyClass2', contains = c('MyClass1'))
```

The MyClass2 2nd generation subclass seems to be significant (without it the warnings go away).  I do not understand why.

I have run a sequence of tests on this code, using `devtools` and 
`roxygen2`.  The tests vary by what is in the NAMESPACE file, and what is
in the Imports directive in the DESCRIPTION file.  Executing the test consists of running `devtools::load_all()` (or `devtools::document()` which calls `load_all()` along the way) in RStudio.  The warning messages which occur have been posted above. I restart my R session in a clean global environment between each test (the warnings only occur the first time I run `load_all` or `document`).

**While following up an answer given below I have realised I should also have tried to build and install my toy package using R from a shell command line.**

### test1

test1 has DESCRIPTION file entry (see the end of this question for the complete DESCRIPTION file):

```
Imports:
    methods,
    sp
```

and the complete NAMESPACE file (generated from roxygen comments omitted above) is :

```
# Generated by roxygen2 (4.1.0.9001): do not edit by hand

importClassesFrom(sp,SpatialLines)
importFrom(sp,SpatialLines)
```

Trying to run `devtools::load_all()` (or `devtools::document()`) in a 
restarted R session generates the first warning (shown above).

**Question 1** Why does R need the ~~(virtual?)~~ superclass `Spatial` anyway, and why only when I have the 2nd generation `MyClass2` defined in my code?   *Clarification added* I had thought that the R packaging namespace mechanism would have taken care of any need to find and access antecedents /  superclasses once I had `@importClassesFrom`ed the class I actually use.

### test2

test2 *resolves* the problem by updating the NAMESPACE file as indicated by
the warning message. No other changes were made.

The warning goes away when the complete NAMESPACE file is :

```
# Generated by roxygen2 (4.1.0.9001): do not edit by hand

importClassesFrom(sp,Spatial)
importClassesFrom(sp,SpatialLines)
importFrom(sp,SpatialLines)
```

### test3

An apparently similar problem recurs though, when I made one small change to 
the Imports directive in the DESCRIPTION file, namely add in `rgeos`.  This is the only change made to create the test3 scenario from test2.

```
Imports:
    methods,
    sp,
    rgeos
```

Now I get a warning that looks like the problem from test1, viz :

```
class "SpatialLinesNULL" is defined (with package slot ‘rgeos’) but no metadata object found to revise subclass information---not exported?  Making a copy in package ‘minweSpatialNULL
```

As far as I have been able to figure out, `SpatialLinesNULL` is a new
superclass of `Spatial`, defined in `rgeos` so it can provide some
generic functions and methods.

**Question 2** I am presuming that whatever the reason is for my first warning message, is also the reason for this similar message.
Am I on the right track?

### test4

In test4 I try to apply the same solution as *worked* in test2, namely add the *missing* entry to the NAMESPACE file.  This is the complete NAMESPACE file for test4.

```
# Generated by roxygen2 (4.1.0.9001): do not edit by hand

importClassesFrom(rgeos,SpatialLinesNULL)
importClassesFrom(sp,Spatial)
importClassesFrom(sp,SpatialLines)
importFrom(sp,SpatialLines)
```

at which stage I get my final error message :

```
d> devtools::document()
Updating minweSpatialNULL documentation
Loading minweSpatialNULL
Error: class "SpatialLinesNULL" is not exported by 'namespace:rgeos
```

At this stage I am stuck.

**Question 3** Is the warning from test3 and this 
subsequent error something I can resolve myself (if so how)? 
or do I need to ask the maintainer of the `rgeos` package
for help (eg ask them to export `SpatialLinesNULL`)?

### session_info (from test4)

```
d> devtools::session_info()
Session info --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (0.98.953)          
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_Australia.1252      
 tz       Australia/Sydney            

Packages ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package          * version    date       source        
 devtools         * 1.7.0.9000 2015-02-20 local         
 lattice          * 0.20-29    2014-04-04 CRAN (R 3.1.2)
 minweSpatialNULL * 0.0.0.9000 <NA>       local         
 Rcpp             * 0.11.4     2015-01-24 CRAN (R 3.1.2)
 rgeos            * 0.3-8      2014-09-21 CRAN (R 3.1.2)
 roxygen2         * 4.1.0.9001 2015-02-21 local         
 rstudio          * 0.98.953   2014-08-02 local         
 rstudioapi       * 0.2        2014-12-31 CRAN (R 3.1.2)
 sp               * 1.0-17     2015-01-08 CRAN (R 3.1.2)
 stringr          * 0.6.2      2012-12-06 CRAN (R 3.1.1)
d>
```

### Complete files for test4

R/myclasses.r

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#' MyClass1
#' 
#' A subclass of SpatialLines
#' 
#' MyClass1 is a subclass of sp::SpatialLines.
#' @importClassesFrom sp SpatialLines Spatial
#' @importFrom sp SpatialLines
#' @importClassesFrom rgeos SpatialLinesNULL
MyClass1 <- setClass('MyClass1', contains = c('SpatialLines'))

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#' MyClass2
#' 
#' A subclass of MyClass1
#' 
#' MyClass2 is a subclass of MyClass1 and a 2nd generation subclass of
#' sp::SpatialLines.
#' @importClassesFrom sp SpatialLines
MyClass2 <- setClass('MyClass2', contains = c('MyClass1'))
```

DESCRIPTION file

```
Package: minweSpatialNULL
Title: Minimum Example of my Problem with SpatialLinesNULL
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: person("Geoff", "Lee", , "geoff.lee@gmail.com", role = c("aut", "cre"))
Description: (Hopefully) demonstrates my problem with warnings
  that I cannot seem to eradicate. 
Depends: R (>= 3.1.2)
Imports:
    methods,
    sp,
    rgeos
License: GPL (>= 2.0)
LazyData: true
```

NAMESPACE file

```
# Generated by roxygen2 (4.1.0.9001): do not edit by hand

importClassesFrom(rgeos,SpatialLinesNULL)
importClassesFrom(sp,Spatial)
importClassesFrom(sp,SpatialLines)
importFrom(sp,SpatialLines)
```

### Conclusion

Many thanks in advance for any help, advice or guidance that can be offered!  Even if it is just about how I might pose a better question :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer draws together all the information I've learnt related to the suite of questions I asked, for the benefit of anyone else who comes across a similar issue.

It turns out to be easier to present the answers in reverse to the order in which the questions were asked.

The aspect which really resolved my specific problem was provided by @Edzer Pebesma - who has my thanks.

John Chambers answered a more specific follow on question I asked on the r-devel mailing list, and that really helped fill in the gaps in my understanding of why the warning message was being given - I am also very grateful for his guidance and assistance.

Any errors that remain in the explanation below are entirely my own!

> The  test4 version of the toy package referenced in this question and answer used to be found in --> folder SpatialLinesNULL of branch SpatialLinesNULL in a github repo at http://github.com/Geoff99/Examples/tree/SpatialLinesNULL <-- Other versions of the test sequence can be constructed by deleting a line or two from the NAMESPACE and DESCRIPTION files.
>
> Update 6 May 2017 - test4 version code moved to a gist at https://gist.github.com/Geoff99/29be25bce4cd4c918921bf68769c6a39

### Question 3 (after test4)

> Is the warning from test3 and this subsequent error something I can resolve myself (if so how)? or do I need to ask the maintainer of the rgeos package for help (eg ask them to export SpatialLinesNULL)?

The warning from test3 was

```
class "SpatialLinesNULL" is defined (with package slot ‘rgeos’) but no metadata object found to revise subclass information---not exported?  Making a copy in package ‘minweSpatialNULL
```

and the error message from test4 was

```
d> devtools::document()
Updating minweSpatialNULL documentation
Loading minweSpatialNULL
Error: class "SpatialLinesNULL" is not exported by 'namespace:rgeos
```

The best solution to this was to approach a maintainer of the `rgeos` package and ask them to export the missing `SpatialLinesNULL` class that is mentioned in the warning and error messages.  Edzer Pebesma answered this for me, and also made the necessary updates to the `rgeos` package, for which I am very grateful.  After installing the upgraded version of package `rgeos` I could simply add `importClassesFrom(rgeos,SpatialLinesNULL)` to the NAMESPACE file of my toy package, and the warning went away.

If you are facing a similar situation with a different package, that is the strategy I would recommend.

I *suspect* that there is a way I could have resolved this myself (essentially by manually making a copy of the missing metadata about the `SpatialLinesNULL class` in the namespace environment of my package, which is basically what the `methods` package does itself after it issues the warning) --- but it is such a messy *hack* that I will refrain from explaining how. If you **really** need to do this at some stage in the future, the answer to question 1 (below) collects the information I needed to understand to figure out how to do the *hack*.

### Question 2 (after test3)

> I am presuming that whatever the reason is for my first warning message, is also the reason for this similar message.
>    Am I on the right track?

The warning from test3 was

```
class "SpatialLinesNULL" is defined (with package slot ‘rgeos’) but no metadata object found to revise subclass information---not exported?  Making a copy in package ‘minweSpatialNULL
```

and the first warning from test1 was

```
class "Spatial" is defined (with package slot ‘sp’) but no metadata object found to revise subclass information---not exported?  Making a copy in package ‘minweSpatialNULL’
```

The answer was **yes**, both messages appear for the same reason.

The warning messages are both being generated by a function called `.findOrCopyClass` with is an internal (ie non-exported) function in the methods package.  To see the code for this function it is necessary to use the `:::` operator.  Type `methods:::.findOrCopyClass` into an R console.  (This requires the methods package to be loaded, which it almost always is). `.findOrCopyClass` issues this warning when it cannot find the *metadata* which defines a class, and so it has to copy the metadata.

See below for what the *metadata* is, why it needs to be included in the namespace for my toy package, and (my best guess) at why this warning is issued.

`.findOrCopyClass` is called by `setIs`, which is an exported function from the `methods` package. In turn `setIs` is called (several times) by the methods function `setClass`, which I call in my toy package example.  Type `?setIs` and `?setClass` for more information about those functions.  Or just type `setIs` or `setClass` in an R console if you want to see their source code.

### Question 1 (after test1)

> Why does R need the ~~(virtual?)~~ superclass Spatial anyway~~, and why only when I have the 2nd generation MyClass2 defined in my code~~?
>
> Clarification added : I had thought that the R packaging namespace mechanism would have taken care of any need to find and access antecedents / superclasses once I had `@importClassesFrom`ed the class I actually use.

#### Apologies and corrections first.

- The part of the original question that asked:

  > and why only when I have the 2nd generation MyClass2 defined in my code?

  was just plain wrong.  Despite my checking before I posted the question, I must have unwittingly still has some hidden information cached in my `globalenv()`.  The underlying issue exists even if I only have `MyClass1` defined in my toy package.
- `Spatial` is not a virtual class. `SpatialLinesNULL` *is* a virtual class.  Whether or not a superclass is virtual has nothing to do with this issue.
- The issue does have a lot to do with

  - Where a superclass is defined (in my toy example, `Spatial` comes from `sp` and `SpatialLinesNULL` comes from `rgeos`)
  - whether the superclass definition is exported from that package (in the toy example, `sp` and `rgeos`)
  - and hence whether and how R can find the superclass definitions when it is checking and installing a new package (eg `minweSpatialNuULL`) which uses a class (eg `SpatialLines`) whose *parents* include superclasses (eg `Spatial`, `SpatialLinesNULL`).

#### What the *missing metadata* warning messages are about

The following is an annotated walk through parts of the documentation for the `methods` package.  It took me a while to grasp, but that is to do with my low knowledge base when I began.  The documentation is very useful, and if you get this far, I would recommend reading it.  I found the entries from `?setClass`, `?Classes`, `?getClassDef`, `?classMetaName` and  `?setIs` particularly valuable.

What `setClass` does

From the `?setClass` documentation (with emphasis added by me) :

> Create a class definition, specifying the representation (the slots) and/or the classes contained in this one (the superclasses), plus other optional details. **As a side effect, the class definition is stored in the specified environment**. A generator function is returned as the value of setClass(), suitable for creating objects from the class if the class is not virtual.

The warning message  issued by `methods:::.findOrCopyClass` is related to the creation and storage of the class definition.  The class definition is (or is stored in?) a metadata object.

What a *metadata object* is

From the `?Classes` documentation :

> Class definitions are objects that contain the formal definition of a class of R objects, ... and
>
> When a class is defined, an **object is stored that contains the information about that class. The object, known as the metadata defining the class**, is not stored under the name of the class (to allow programmers to write generating functions of that name), but under a specially constructed name. To examine the class definition, call `getClass`. The **information in the metadata object includes**:
>
> - Slots ...
> - **SuperClasses** ...
>
>   - The information about the relation between a class and a particular superclass is encoded as an object of class SClassExtension. A list of such objects for the superclasses (and sometimes for the subclasses) is included in the metadata object defining the class
> - Prototype ...

The `methods` package is all about creating and managing these metadata objects (for S4 classes, and as best as it can, for the older S3 classes as well).

The metadata object for a new class (eg `MyClass1`) includes information about any slots in its definition (since `MyClass1` specifies `contains = c('SpatialLines')`  it inherits all the slots from the `SpatialLines` class, defined in package `sp`).

Importantly, the metadata object for a class must *also* contain information about any superclasses - otherwise how could the new class ever inherit anything from its parents, ie the superclasses ? And one way and another, that information about superclasses must reach all the way up the inheritance tree. In the example, `MyClass1` has a distance one superclass `SpatialLines`, and hence inherits all the more distant ancestors of `SpatialLines`, whoever they may be.

- I think I read somewhere, but have mislaid the link, that the metadata object can be in two states - incomplete or complete.  In the incomplete state, the list of superclasses for a new class (eg `MyClass1`) may not (yet) have been filled in all the way up the inheritance chain, whereas by the time a class definition is used, R has to have traversed the inheritance chain, and filled in the complete *genealogy* for the class. When a package is checked or installed, the inheritance chain must be complete - if it has not been completed before, it has to be during the `install.packages` step.

How to look at a metadata object

Use `getClass` or `getClassDef` to *see* the metadata object for a given class.

The documentation `?getClass` or `?getClassDef` explains which environments R searches for metadata objects. A key thing to note is that a package must *at least* be loaded before metadata objects from classes defined in the package can be found.

Here are some examples from my toy package (`minweSpatialNULL`) after it has been loaded with version 0.3-9 of `rgeos`, which does export the `SpatialLinesNULL` class.  Notice that:

- `MyClass1` knows all its parent superclasses (the usual situation), and
- `SpatialLinesNULL` (which is a *Class Union* defined in the `rgeos` package) knows *almost* all its children *subclasses*, even though `rgeos` itself knows nothing at all about `MyClass1` or `MyClass2` !

  ```
  d> getClass('MyClass1')
  Class "MyClass1" [package "minweSpatialNULL"]

  Slots:

  Name:        lines        bbox proj4string
  Class:        list      matrix         CRS

  Extends: 
  Class "SpatialLines", directly
  Class "Spatial", by class "SpatialLines", distance 2
  Class "SpatialLinesNULL", by class "SpatialLines", distance 2

  Known Subclasses: "MyClass2"


  d> getClass('SpatialLinesNULL')
  Extended class definition ( "ClassUnionRepresentation" )
  Virtual Class "SpatialLinesNULL" [package "rgeos"]

  No Slots, prototype of class "NULL"

  Known Subclasses: 
  Class "NULL", directly
  Class "SpatialLines", directly
  Class ".NULL", by class "NULL", distance 2, with explicit coerce
  Class "SpatialLinesDataFrame", by class "SpatialLines", distance 2
  Class "MyClass2", by class "MyClass1", distance 3
  d>
  ```
- Actually it is slightly curious that `SpatialLinesNULL` knows about `MyClass2` because it is a subclass of `MyClass1`, but does **not** appear to mention `MyClass1` itself directly.  I haven't figured out why yet.

Why the list of superclasses can change

I was puzzled for a while as to why the list of superclasses of my toy `MyClass1` class changed when I made no change to my package other than adding `rgeos` to the `Imports` directive in the toy package's DESCRIPTION file.

The reason is that the methods package is very clever.  As well as defining subclasses, it is possible to insert **parent superclasses** into the family tree (inheritance chain) of a class, **after** that class has been defined.

A simple way is to use `setClassUnion` (type `?setClassUnion` for an explanation).  That is what `rgeos` does when it defines `SpatialLinesNULL` - it creates a new parent for `SpatialLines`.  And that is why as soon as I added the `rgeos` entry in my toy package DESCRIPTION file, the class `MyClass1` suddenly acquired another superclass as well. In an interactive setting something similar would presumably have happened, depending on whether or not I had loaded (or attached and loaded) the `rgeos` package.

There is a more complicated way to add ancestors *after the fact* as well - see `?setIs`.

The names of metadata objects

As with all other objects, R finds metadata objects via their name.  If an object is defined in a package, the name of the object lives in

- the namespace environment of the package (eg `environment: namespace:minweSpatialNULL`), or
- the imports environment of the package (eg `environment: imports:minweSpatialNULL`).

From the `?Classes` documentation again :

> When a class is defined, an object is stored that contains the information about that class. The object, known as the metadata defining the class, **is not stored under the name of the class** (to allow programmers to write generating functions of that name), **but under a specially constructed name.**

You can find the specially constructed name using the `classMetaName` function which the methods package provides - see `?methods::classMetaName` for details.

An example of the *name* of a metadata object, taken from my toy package, is :

```
d> classMetaName('MyClass1')
[1] ".__C__MyClass1"
```

Because of the leading `.` the  name of this metadata object (ie `.__C__MyClass1`) is usually hidden when you `ls` the namespace environment of the package - but you can see it by using the `all.names = TRUE` argument to `ls`.

```
d> # Recall that MyClass1 is the name I chose for the generator function 
d> #  returned by setClass when I defined the class MyClass1
d> env_toy_package <- environment(MyClass1)
d> ls(env_toy_package, all.names=TRUE)
[1] ".__C__MyClass1"       ".__C__MyClass2"       ".__DEVTOOLS__"       
[4] ".__NAMESPACE__."      ".__S3MethodsTable__." ".packageName"        
[7] "MyClass1"             "MyClass2"            
d>
```

And if you look in the `parent.env` of the package namespace environment (ie the `imports:minweSpatialNULL` namespace environment), you find the hidden names of the superclasses of `MyClass1`, which is what `.findOrCopyClass` was looking for so they  could be put there!.

```
d> parent.env(env_toy_package)
<environment: 0x0000000008df59d8>
attr(,"name")
[1] "imports:minweSpatialNULL"

d> ls(parent.env(env_toy_package), all.names = TRUE)
[1] ".__C__Spatial"          ".__C__SpatialLines"     ".__C__SpatialLinesNULL"
[4] "library.dynam.unload"   "SpatialLines"           "system.file"           
d>
```

**Finally**, what the '.findOrCopyClass` warning is about

When `.findOrCopyClass` issues a warning such as :

```
class "Spatial" is defined (with package slot ‘sp’) but no metadata object found to revise subclass information---not exported?  Making a copy in package ‘minweSpatialNULL’
```

the function is letting me know that it has been unable to find the *hidden* name `.__C__Spatial` in the namespaces it has searched and revise the metadata in the object to which that name is bound.  It knows where the hidden name *should* be --- it must come from package `sp`, because the metadata object from the `SpatialLines` class itself says where its parent superclass (`Spatial`) lives.  The full specification of an ancestor superclass in a metadata object includes a `package` attribute containing the name of the package where the ancestor superclass was defined, *just* in case two existing loaded packages just happen to have chosen the same name for a class!

That is why `importClassesFrom`ing the missing superclass works - it brings the missing *hidden* names into the `imports:minweSpatialNULL` environment of the `minweSpatialNULL` toy package, from which spot `.findOrCopyClass` can find them, and update them if necessary.

Why `.findOrCopy` emits a warning

I wondered why `.findOrCopyClass` told me it couldn't find the metadata object, when the very next thing it said was that it was making a copy in my packages namespace!  I posed that question on the r-devel mailing list, and John Chambers kindly answered it for me (emphases added by me):

> the purpose of finding the class definition is to update the entry for the new relationship, as the warning message suggests.  That requires that **the namespace holding the definition be writable**.
>
> In the case of subclass information, **the original namespace is very likely to be locked**, if it's not the package currently being loaded.  Copying the definition in order to update subclass information seems the only reasonable choice, and no warning message is needed.
>
> A revised version will omit this message.

My remaining conceptual problem related to the difference between what happens to the *name* of an object (eg a function or a class (to be precise, a function object or a class metadata object)) and what happens to the *object* itself. Or in other terms, whether a namespace (possibly locked) needs to be updated, or the (state of the) object itself is what needs to be updated.

It turns out that '`findorCopyClasses` is not complaining that it cannot find the (non-exported) superclass, but rather that it cannot find it **in a place where the superclass's value can be changed**.

What locked means

The `?base::bindenv` documentation says :

> " The namespace environments of packages with namespaces are locked 
>   when loaded."

and a locked environment means

> " prevents adding or removing variable bindings from the environment.
>   Changing the value of a variable is still possible unless the binding has been locked"

But a bit experimentation reveals  that as well as package namespace
*environments* being locked, the **bindings** in the imports:namespace are locked.  Locked bindings means that :

> " The value of a locked binding cannot be changed".

Hence since the superclass metadata object comes from another package (eg `rgeos`), its binding in that other package's namespace is locked and hence its value cannot be changed.  Or in terms of the example, when the methods package wants to add `Myclass1` and `MyClass2` to the  list of *subclasses* that `SpatialLinesNULL` 'owns', it finds it cannot because the binding of `SpatialLinesNULL` (or to be precise, the binding of the hidden name `.__C__SpatialLinesNULL`) is locked. Hence the message about needing to make a copy!

An alternative to copying *might* be to temporarily unlock the binding in the namespace of the otherpackage, update the object, and relock the binding - but since I have only just learnt about locking environments and bindings, I have no idea what the consequences of that might be.  I'll leave well enough alone.

OK, How to *hack* a solution if the required superclass is not exported

**Caveat** I haven't tested this much, and it's a **bad** idea anyway, but if you are really really desperate to get the warning message to go away ...

Step1.  Look at the warning message and find the (text) name of the missing superclass, and the package it comes from.

Step2.  Use `classMetaName` to find the hidden and mangled name of the missing unexported superclass.  For superclass `MissingSuperclass` it will probably be `.__C__MissingSuperclass`

Step3.  Use the `:::` approach to access the metadata object (ie `donorpackage:::.__C__MissingSuperclass`) and give it the appropriate name (ie `.__C__MissingSuperclass`) in the appropriate environment belonging to your package, before calling `setClass` to create your own class.

As I've already said, this is a really **bad** idea, since it would be enormously easy to shoot yourself in the foot, and why bother anyway, since that's essentially what `.findOrCopyClass` and `setIs` seem to do after the warning message has been sent anyway.

### The end

If you've read this far, I hope this has helped you!  I've written it at such length mostly as a tutorial for a future me :-)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for this extensive question. I have two suggestions to improve it. First, provide a reproducible example, which in this case would be a minimal package that lets us reproduce your warning or error messages. For instance,

```
MyClass1 <- setClass('MyClass1', contains = c('SpatialLines'))
MyClass2 <- setClass('MyClass2', contains = c('MyClass1'))
```

works fine in a session that has `sp` loaded, but the problem you have appears when doing this in your package code. Creating such a package means doing a lot of guess work: we don't see your complete `NAMESPACE`, so don't know what you export, and want to have work in an R session after loading your package. Second: isolate your problem from those caused by using `devtools` (i.e., use the standard R package development terminology of building and installing a package).

From what you provide, I can only answer:

- Q1: `Spatial` is not a virtual class, and it is there because it defines what all derived classes have in common (a CRS and a bounding box), and it is needed because there are methods defined for it that operate on all derived classes. `MyClass2` needing it is related to your package, which I don't have
- Q2: I can't answer because you don't show the warning that led to Q1. Also, `SpatialLinesNULL` is not a superclass of `Spatial` but of `SpatialLines`, defined by

  `setClassUnion("SpatialLinesNULL", c("SpatialLines", "NULL"))`
- Q3: you may try by compiling a modified version of `rgeos` that exports this class; if you provide a good use case (a minimal package that reproduces your problem), one of the developers of `rgeos` will look into it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll see what happens when I separate out the use of `devtools` aspect, and report back what I learn / update my question accordingly.

Comment: Is there a recommended or preferred way of posting a toy package?  Should I just post a comment with the files here (one for each of my 4 successive tests) or is there somewhere I can post a zip file> <Sorry if this is an obvious question with a standard answer I should have already read, if so please just point me in the direction of the appropriate documentation so I can learn more about how to use StackOverflow well>

Comment: put a link in a comment to a source package (a file), or to a github repo with the package.

Comment: **Progress Report**


@Edzer Pebesma's answer has been very helpful.

I have investigated what happens when I try to build and check my toy package from a shell command line using `Rscript` or `R cmd` directly --- and the behaviour that caused me to pose this question seems to disappear.  I need to investigate more thoroughly, but *at the moment* it appears that there is something about how I am using `devtools` that is the source of my problem.


I will continue to investigate, and update details and a final answer if possible when I have the problem solved.

Thanks :-)

Comment: **Correction** On closer inspection it turns out that I still get the warning (or error) messages when I use `R CMD build .` followed by `R CMD check *.gz` (this is where the warning message appears).I also get the messages when I use `RScript` to run `devtools::load_all` outside RStudio

Comment: Dear @Edzer Thank you for your earlier advice.  I thought I was getting close to a solution, but no joy.   I have placed the test4 version of my toy package in folder SpatialLinesNULL of branch SpatialLinesNULL in a github repo at http://github.com/Geoff99/Examples/tree/SpatialLinesNULL   Other versions of the test sequence can be constructed by deleting a line or two from the NAMESPACE and DESCRIPTION files.  Any further advice would be very gratefully received (esp since the question is too long :-( by far).  I am currently reading the internals of `setClass` and `initialize` seeking clues.

Comment: Thanks, I can reproduce this if `NAMESPACE` also imports `rgeos`. I committed the change to rgeos to also exportClass SpatialLinesNULL (and all other Spatial*NULL classes); you'll find the package at https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=602

Comment: Many thanks indeed @Edzer  Really appreciate your taking the time to help me.  It is suppertime my time now, but I'll access the changed rgeos and test it out first thing tomorrow.  In my real project I also use SpatialPolygonsDataFrame so much appreciate your thinking to include the other Spatial*NULL classes as well.

Comment: Hi @Edzer.  Just tested rgeos 0.3-9, SVN 467 in both my toy example, and my real project.  Warning messages totally gone. My practical problem is resolved :-) Still curious as to why the R packaging and namespacing mechanism does not automagically find and register the superclasses when it loads and checks a package (either my toy or real packages) so I'll keep my question open for a bit while I look into that for curiosity's sake, and post an answer here if I find one.  Essentially though, my problem is fixed due to your help.  I'm very grateful. Thank you!